# How to install a certificate on Android TV?

Tags: fiddler, android-tv, android-settings

I've installed certificates (especially the FiddlerRootCA) on several android devices already, since it has a security section in the menus.

On Android TV on the other hand, I was not able to find anything in the settings, altough I went through them? I would like to install the certificate here on my Android TV stick, on which I have adb root access to.

How can I install a certificate on my Android TV?

Comment: Is your question from a user perspective or from an app developer perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to install custom certificat in Android user build (certificats list check is part or Google certification). Nevertheless you can load custom certificat in you application with keyStore and keyManagerFactory API.